# Get number of blocks allocated on the heap to detect memory leaks

Tags: c++, visual-studio, memory-leaks

Is there a function available that can get the number of blocks of memory that are currently allocated on the heap? It can be Windows/Visual Studio specific.

I'd like to use that to check if a function leaks memory, without using a dedicated profiler. I'm thinking about something like this:

```
int before = AllocatedBlocksCount();
foo();
if (AllocatedBlocksCount() > before)
    printf("Memory leak!!!");
```

Comment: just run your code in a loop and check out the task manager :P

Comment: That could be used as a substitute if no such a function is available, yes. Not always though, some functions just can't be run a loop, because they read from sockets etc., and the server won't resend the same data. Sometimes the state is changed and the function can't be run the same way a second time. This could be done only for very simple functions.

Comment: @Alon there can be huge discrepancies between heap memory allocated and OS (task) memory reserved.

Comment: For CRT, have you tried these functions? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x98tx3cf.aspx

Comment: Thanks, _CrtMemDifference seems to be what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are several ways to do it (specific to the CRT that comes with Microsoft Visual Studio.)

One way would be to use the `_CrtMemCheckpoint()` function before and after the call you are interested in, and then compare the difference with `_CrtMemDifference()`.

```
_CrtMemState s1, s2, s3;

_CrtMemCheckpoint (&s1);
foo(); // Memory allocations take place here
_CrtMemCheckpoint (&s2);

if (_CrtMemDifference(&s3, &s1, &s2)) // Returns true if there's a difference
   _CrtMemDumpStatistics (&s3);
```

You can also enumerate all the allocated blocks using `_CrtDoForAllClientObjects()`, and a couple of other methods using the debug routines of the Visual C++ CRT.

Notes:

- All these are in the `<crtdbg.h>` header.
- They obviously work only on Windows and when compiling with VC.
- You need to set up CRT debugging and a few flags and other things.
- These are rather tricky features; make sure to read the relevant parts of the MSDN carefully.
- These **only** work in debug mode (i.e. linking with the debug CRT and the `_DEBUG` macro defined.)

Comment: I added the code from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/x98tx3cf.aspx, I hope it's not a problem.

Comment: @sashoalm: Absolutely not! Thanks.